# Configuring Different repo path for pgbackrest wal archive

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have installed and started using pgbackrest for postgresql incremental backups. Everything is working fine but i have a requirement to have separate repository for archived wals from the base backups. In pgbackrest documentation i can find only one setting for both.

repo1-path=/var/lib/pgbackrest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up by setting a symbolic link for the archive directory after creating the stanza and working perfectly.